# c# recursively decompose class

Tags: c#, recursion

I don't know if the title of the topic is correct, but here's what I want.

Let's say I have a class, which in it's turn can have another classes, and so on.

What I want, it's to get the field's of the classes, eventually in a List generic, with multiple levels.

For example, let's say I have this:

```
class address
{
public string street;
public string number;
}

class Student
{
public string name;
public string surname;
public address addr;
}
```

For example, I need a method

```
Student s;
getItems(s);
```

which will return me a list which will contain: name, surname, and another list which will contain street and number.

I tried this:

```
public void getItems(Object o, List<object> list)
        {
            FieldInfo[] f = new FieldInfo[o.GetType().GetFields().Length];

           f = o.GetType().GetFields();                            

            foreach (FieldInfo fi in f)
            {                    
                if (fi.GetType().GetFields().Length > 0)
                {
                    List<object> newList = new List<object>();
                    list.Add(newList);

                    getItems(fi, newList);
                }
                else
                {
                    list.Add(fi.Name);
                }
            }                                                
        }
```

but it only get to the first level. The first parameter is the object I want to decompose, and the second a list object which will return the class.
Can you help me guys?
Thanks.

Comment: So why should string not be broken up into an object with a length property?  What makes it special?  What other types are "special" and shouldn't be broken down any further?

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger and setting a breakpoint on the line `if (pi.GetType().GetFields().Length > 0)`? Then look what the value of `pi.GetType().GetFields()` is when `pi` points to the address.

Comment: But I need the list on multiple levels, according to each object. I hope I'm being clear on this.

Comment: Do you want the values as well? As getting the values is incredibly difficult when you consider types like DateTime and arrays of complex types. I had a similar issue with this and in the end I just wrote an interface called something like `IProvidesFields` and wrote the method to return the fields manually. Not super clever, but it worked.

Comment: Yes, I have used a debugger, and here's where the thing goes wrong. pi.GetType().GetFields().Length will return 0 I think

Comment: To SLC - yes I will need the values as well.

Comment: @user2536272 If the 'Length' is 0, then have you checked that `pi.GetType()` and `pi.GetType().GetFields()` show the expected results? If not, what is wrong with them?

Comment: The problem I'm having is that it iterates correctly through name, and surname, but when it gets to addr,  fi.GetType().GetFields() doesn't return something like an array with street and number. I'm asking you more advanced guys which method should I use instead of .GetType().GetFields(). I get System.Reflection.FieldInfo[0]

Answer (score 1):

This kind of thing is perfect for writing tests to figure out the way to go!

In short the method you want is something very like:

```
        List<string> GetFieldNames(IEnumerable<FieldInfo> fields)
        {
            var results = new List<string>();

            foreach (var fieldInfo in fields)
            {
                if (fieldInfo.FieldType.GetFields().Count() > 1)
                {
                    results.AddRange(GetFieldNames(fieldInfo.FieldType.GetFields()));
                }
                else
                {
                    results.Add(fieldInfo.Name);
                }
            }
            return results;
        }
```

A full test class that demonstrates the function (and my figuring out) is:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace stackoverflow_tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class ReflectionTest
    {
        class Address
        {
            public string Street;
            public string Number;
        }

        class Student
        {
            public string Name;
            public string Surname;
            public Address Address;
        }

        [Test]
        public void ShouldDisplayNestedClassFields()
        {
            var student = new Student();
            var studentFields = student.GetType().GetFields();

            Assert.IsNotNull(studentFields);
            Assert.AreEqual(3, studentFields.Count());

            var expectedNames = new []{"Name", "Surname", "Address"};
            var expectedTypes = new[] {typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(Address)};

            for (var fieldIndex = 0; fieldIndex < 3; fieldIndex++)
            {
                var field = studentFields[fieldIndex];
                var fieldName = field.Name;
                Assert.AreEqual(expectedNames[fieldIndex], fieldName);

                var fieldType = field.FieldType;
                Assert.AreEqual(expectedTypes[fieldIndex], fieldType);

                var childFields = field.FieldType.GetFields();
                var childFieldCount = childFields.Count();
                var expectedFieldCount = fieldIndex == 2 ? 2 : 1;
                Assert.AreEqual(expectedFieldCount, childFieldCount);
            }
        }

        [Test]
        public void CanGetFieldNames()
        {
            var expectedResults = new List<string> {"Name", "Surname", "Street", "Number"};
            var student = new Student();
            var actual = GetFieldNames(student.GetType().GetFields());
            Assert.AreEqual(expectedResults, actual);
        }

        List<string> GetFieldNames(IEnumerable<FieldInfo> fields)
        {
            var results = new List<string>();

            foreach (var fieldInfo in fields)
            {
                if (fieldInfo.FieldType.GetFields().Count() > 1)
                {
                    results.AddRange(GetFieldNames(fieldInfo.FieldType.GetFields()));
                }
                else
                {
                    results.Add(fieldInfo.Name);
                }
            }
            return results;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that fi.GetType() doesn't return the type "address" but returns an FieldInfo...

You may want to test the fi.FieldType...

```
public static void getItems(Object o, List<object> list)
{
    FieldInfo[] f = new FieldInfo[o.GetType().GetFields().Length];

   f = o.GetType().GetFields();                            

    foreach (FieldInfo fi in f)
    {                    
        if (fi.FieldType.GetFields().Length > 0)
        {
            List<object> newList = new List<object>();
            list.Add(newList);

            getItems(fi, newList);
        }
        else
        {
            list.Add(fi.Name);
        }
    }                                                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've finally managed to get this done.
For guys that want the actual code, here it is:

```
    public void getItems(Type t, List<object> list)
    {
       foreach(FieldInfo fi in t.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
       {
           list.Add(fi.Name);

           if(!fi.FieldType.Namespace.Equals("System"))
           {
               List<object> newList = new List<object>();
               list.Add(newList);
               getItems(fi.FieldType, newList);
           }
       }
    }
```